# mkstemp implicit declaration of function

Tags: c, cygwin, mkstemp

I have a problem with the function `mkstemp()`. GCC compiler on `cygwin` generates a warning:

```
implicit declaration of function ‘mkstemp‘
```

GCC flags: `-std=c99 -Wall`

Includes:

```
#include </usr/include/stdlib.h>
#include </usr/include/unistd.h>
```

Comment: from the manpage: #include <stdlib.h> why misleading the compiler to a specific path?

Comment: Yes the hard-coded path is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

In my `cygwin` `stdlib.h` has `mkstemp` declaration guarded like this:

```
#ifndef __STRICT_ANSI__
#ifndef _REENT_ONLY
int _EXFUN(mkstemp,(char *));
#endif
```

Seems like `mkstemp` is not `ANSI C`. Make sure you don't have your compiler set to enforce a specific standard (ditch the `c99`) and don't use `-ansi/-pedantic` flags.

Also ... ditch the `/usr/include/` part in your `#include`s. The compiler takes care of that for you.

Comment: I wanted to enforce standard c99 because of "‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode"

Comment: You could use `-std=gnu99` instead (but beware: this causes some non-conforming behavior in the compiler, including certain floating point breakage) or `-U__STRICT_ANSI__` to omit the `__STRICT_ANSI__` macro while keeping C99 features.